# WEB API DESIGN: Are fragmented GET requests to build a page's content a symptom of bad design?

Tags: database-design, api-design, web-api

If I find myself fetching one peice of data, and then fetching its 'related data' in a separate request, is this bad API design considering I could package all of this data into one response object?

To provide some context:

If I am viewing a product's page, I find myself fetching the product's specific data, and then fetching related data like 'a list of related products',or a 'list of related articles', etc.

I would also appreciate if someone could give me some insight into the terminology of what I am talking about. I am mainly concerned with how I package data, how I build the API, and how I know I am doing this all efficiently.

Comment: It seems like a fairly common problem. Infact facebook had to invent http://graphql.org/ to solve it.

Comment: Making multiple requests is not bad API design – your API has multiple endpoints that do a single thing each. Great! But you have a problem if (a) the queries are too diverse to cleanly map to a stable API → use GraphQL instead. Or if (b) the multiple requests add noticeable latency on page load, which might hurt conversions → try server-side rendering. If you really need an SPA, create an API that transfers the whole data model for a complete page with a single endpoint. That is easily doable with content negotiation: HTML → render page model as HTML. JSON → render as JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not qualify as bad design if the UI isn't making several requests for the same information over and over.  There are many negative aspects to it, but it seems like you could benefit from another API layer to consolidate things.

I inherited an app that had a number of Web Service bound controls which would make another web call when setting its initial state even though that state was provided when a page was loaded.  That would be an example of bad design.

I also worked on an app that had micro services, and the UI had to collect information from each micro-service.  Each call was made once and web calls were only made when there was a justifiable reason for it (i.e. actually changing data).

That said, frameworks like GraphQL and Falcor exist because of the micro-services layer.  Both of these products provide a graph API to populate and change data.  Both of those products manage both client and server side caching.

Pros and Cons of Graph APIs:

- Easily consolidates the call for all information on a page into one
- Handles client/server communications on your behalf (including cache invalidations)
- Learning curve is very steep
- Graphs don't always map to your micro services easily

It is pretty cool being able to ask the graph API, Falcor in my case, to get a list of items with the specific columns you want.  Matching that with a React UI was also pretty easy to do.

The challenge I ran into is that now you have a server endpoint that in turn integrates with your other web services to respond to the graph queries.  Creating routes and responding to them takes some getting used to--particularly when changing a field on a piece of data required updating the whole document.

Answer (score 3):

Everything in software is a trade-off related to developer efficiency and application performance. Are you experiencing too much burden on the server because of the extra request? What is the reason you can't bundle the extra info into the main request? Are there tons of other apps that use the main request without needing the extra info? These are all questions you must ask yourself, before deciding **if** or **how** to alter the code. If the software is logically best separated by having it the way it is now, and you are not experiencing any current burden on the server, I would leave it as-is, with maybe just a plan for the future if the burden becomes noticeable.

As a rule, I do not try to solve problems that I do not have! (Usually applied to issues of software performance versus maintainability)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Even though I may or may not have these problems currently, I am having trouble gauging the implementations of future-proof architectures in order to not have specific problems in the future (as the # of users rise). I guess this is where tried and true frameworks come into play?

Comment: @connected_user: There's no such thing as a future proof architecture.  You can make some educated guesses about how to best approach architectural decisions, but your best results are going to derive from real-world assessments and resulting efforts against *actual problems you are having now,* not imagined future ones.

Comment: @connected_user: Also, the problems that Facebook faces are very likely not the same problems you have right now.  In the unlikely event that your company grows to Facebook size, your scaling challenges will be a good problem to have, and you'll have the money you need to deal with them *then.*

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

It's good to offer/create a flexible api to begin with. But at the end of the day you will want to optimise so you can server the pages as quickly and cheaply (in terms of server costs) as possible.

I wouldn't lose the existing APIs completely, but I would add a combined call allowing you to save the round trip for the use case you have.

Aim to get all pages loading from cache or CDN.